# disable someone without permission get access to power bi report

Tags: powerbi, azure-active-directory

I've generated a power bi report and published it on Power bi Service designed for specific individuals. But it turns out someone in my company without permission still could get access to the report only by entering the url of the corresponding report on browser.

I tried to configure report-level permission in a power bi Premium Per User account:

1. Inside the workspace, click on the report I want to secure.
2. Click on "File",  then "manage permissions",
3. Click the vertical 3 dots besides the url, choose "manage access", then input a specific email address of person A, but it turns out Person B in my organization without permission still can get access to the report.

Any thoughts about this? Thanks in advance.
I've heard Azure AD is also an feasible way but didn't try that as I need to apply for an account first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person B may still have access if they have access to the Workspace. Or if you have allowed other users to re-share. Or Person B is in a group that the report has been shared to.

Check the following:

- Links (like you have done above) and check if "Re-share" is enabled.
- Next to Links, go to Direct access - and check all those in there.
- In the Workspace, select "Manage access" at the top and see if Person B is in there.

Comment: It works after following your instructions. Thank you so much.@Sam Nseir

Comment: Good to hear, please help to Accept the answer for the benefit of all.